# Regular expression for multiple matching in a hierarchical string

Tags: python, regex, class-hierarchy

I would like to extract a hierarchical string into a multiple matching result.

For example:

```
   F           21           W          2121            /02 

[A-Z]{1}   [0-9]{1,n}   [A-Z]{1}    [0-9]{1,n}    /{1}[0-9]{1,n}
```

Result:

```
F21W2121/02 -> F, F21, F21W, F21W2121, F21W2121/02 

G06Q30/00 -> G, G06, G06Q, G06Q30, G06Q30/00
```

Is any good idea to parse this? I have been stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^((((([A-Z])\d+)[A-Z])\d+)/\d+)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7oI6/3)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "F21W2121/02"
>>> re.findall(r'^((((([A-Z])\d+)[A-Z])\d+)/\d+)$', s)
[('F21W2121/02', 'F21W2121', 'F21W', 'F21', 'F')]
>>> re.findall(r'^((((([A-Z])\d+)[A-Z])\d+)/\d+)$', "G06Q30/00")
[('G06Q30/00', 'G06Q30', 'G06Q', 'G06', 'G')]
```

Comment: I think the numbers are variable, `[0-9]{1,n}` in the original pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something:

```
>>> import re
>>> ptrn = '((((([A-Z])[0-9]+)[A-Z])[0-9]+)/[0-9]+)'
>>> re.match(ptrn, 'G06Q30/00').groups()
('G06Q30/00', 'G06Q30', 'G06Q', 'G06', 'G')
>>> re.match(ptrn, 'F21W2121/02').groups()
('F21W2121/02', 'F21W2121', 'F21W', 'F21', 'F')
```

You can simply reverse the tuple to get the matches in the order of length.

Comment: Drop all the `{1}` and turn `{1,}` to `+`